# The 'Text' property is read-only and cannot be set

Tags: error

When site permissions from my home page I get the following error

> The 'Text' property is read-only and cannot be set'.

I only get this error from my home page site permissions. I cannot access any document library from view all site content option either strange...

I checked to see if the page was checked out and published and all is well there.

Has anybody had a similar issue if so how did you correct it?

Comment: No I did not modify the code in any way. The Version of SharePoint is 2010.
I have made no changes to that the page at all and I amde sure that the page was checked in as well this is very odd that the error only occurs on the home page none of the other pages are affected...

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance modify the master page being used by the page in question?  If so, look and see if you checked it in.  If you have try checking it out and re-checking back in.